# How to create keyboard shortcut for WiFi toggle?

Tags: keyboard, wifi, shortcut

I want to create keyboard shortcut for Turning ON WiFi when it is turned OFF, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Find out device ID of Wi-Fi

```
$networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep Wi-Fi
(2) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en0)
```

In this case it is `en0`

**Step 2:** Create a "Quick Action" using Automator.app. Set "no input" in "workflow receives" in "any application". Drag and drop "Run Shell Script" and add the following shell script to the text field.

```
if ( networksetup -getairportpower en0 | grep -q Off ); then 
 echo "network is off. turning ON";
 networksetup -setairportpower en0 on 
else echo "network is ON. turning OFF"; 
 networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
fi
```

Save the file in automator as, say, wifi-toggle

**Step 3:** Set keyboard shortcut by going to Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services

Scroll down. Look under "General". You should see an entry for "wifi-toggle"

Comment: Not all WiFi map to en0 but this is a great start to scripting and works for most MacBook line out of the box.

Comment: check this script also which is independent of ethernet port number. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/276272/341892