# Mojave and Catalina slows down with no internet access

Tags: mojave, catalina

For security reasons, our workstations are disabled from accessing the internet. From installation of Mojave, if the OS detects an Ethernet connection, it attempts many times to reach internet leading to slow down the station, mainly the launch of apps takes several minutes.

Workaround : unplug Ethernet wire at boot time, then replug before mounting shared volumes...

The internet access solves the issue.

In Console : many errors concerning daemons :

- NSURLSessiond
- trustd
- passd
- parsecd
- others

HTTP load failed (error code : -999 or -1001).

Avid confirms this issue : http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/Troubleshooting/Pro-Tools-Launches-Slowly-when-Local-Network-Is-Not-Connected-to-Internet

Due to :

- ProTools' PACE
- DSig macOS

Apple Support says :

- upgrade to Catalina : same issue
- set IPv6 to local only : no solve it

Context :

- Mojave 6 & Catalina 2
- Software Titles (not exhaustive) :
- Adobe CC > 16.00 (PP, AE, etc.)
- ProTools > 12
- Libre Office 6.0.7
- Hardware :
- MP6,1
- MM8,1
- only one Ethernet port plugged
- NAS (with Samba)

How to avoid this slowdown which makes the computer practically unusable?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I read this several times but don't see a question anywhere.  Please see [ask] and [edit] your question to clearly indicate the problem you're facing and what you need help with.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for your answer, edited.

Comment: Did you try blocking the process with a firewall so it can get quick response.

Comment: @JeanBonot see if the equivalent of this for ethernet would be useful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194368/turn-wifi-off-on-with-a-single-key/194372#194372

Comment: @NaveedAbbas : This is, several, daemons, we aren't able to block from GUI firewall. I.e. trustd location is /usr/ibexec/trustd

I tried with or without firewall (ALF) enabled. Same result.

Comment: @ankii : WiFi disabled in System Preferences/Network.`networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` shows only en0 (Eth1) and en1 (Eth2) and ThB bridge.

Comment: I use littlesnitch. It provides good control. Offers a free trial

Comment: Thks, but the goal is to remove all internet access at the VLAN-level (switch level 3).

Comment: @JeanBonot then why not turn them off ?

Comment: Ok. I just made `networksetp -setairportpower en2 off`. It doesn't work.

Comment: Confirmation : enabling macOS DSig validation from crl.apple.com and ocsp.apple.com works.
The apps (tested with Adobe CC and LibO) launches normally.
But it's not a defintive solution for us.
Apple support proposed only a generic feedback.