# Is there a simple MacOS Bluetooth Toggle Shell Command?

Tags: macos, command-line, automator, bluetooth

I have found this answer that shows how to toggle WiFi using a keyboard shortcut: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/194372/406298.

I have created a new Action in the automater app to run the shell command provided in the answer:

```
networksetup -getairportpower en1 | grep "On" && networksetup -setairportpower en1 off || networksetup -setairportpower en1 on
```

Then, I have added the Actions shortcut in the keyboard's Touchbar to toggle WiFi from the Touchbar.

This works great as a quick WiFi toggle from the touchbar. However, I would like to do the same for Blutooth. Is there a similar simple shell command to toggle Bluetooth?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third-party utility named [**blueutil**](https://github.com/toy/blueutil) that makes it easy:

```
blueutil --power toggle
```

Toggles the **Bluetooth** power state.

See the **Usage** section on the linked webpage for additional usage information.

**Note**: If you do toggle the power state, turning **Bluetooth** off, make sure you can control your Mac's keyboard via **USB** or built-in if a notebook.